# Apache: how to make directories 'secure'

Tags: php, apache, security, amazon-ec2

I think this is a 'simple' question but I would like to have a correct vision of the problem.

I created an EC2 instance on Amazon using Amazon Linux AMI.
Then I installed Apache and php55.

Let's consider this scenario:
- I have a php web application that has one configuraton file config.php where we store some important info for security of the application, like db credential, login criteria.
- In some files I used include("configuration/config.php")
- I putted the config.php in a "/configuration" directory under /var/html setted 775
- the config.php is actually setted 404 so that I will upgrade to 604 only if I will need some changes and then I will downgrade again to 404

I would like to have config.php and /configuration dir very secured, avoiding some bad user to look into it and getting info inside the file. In this way I could put any 'critical' file inside that subdir.

So is there anything I can do that I didn't yet?
Is better to think to put /configuration dir outside /var/html public dir? If yes, how?

best regards,
Matt

Comment: Yes, store the configuration directory outside of your document root and include it where needed. Ideally you only have an entry script (e.g. index.php) and necessary css, js, font etc. files in your document root.

Comment: Hi, so where do you suggest to create configuration dir? .... directly under /www.... so /www/configuration or somewhere else?

Comment: I suggest just one level above the document root.

Answer (score 1):

I posted here one step more of my testing:

Finally I made in this way (this is only for testing purpose):

in document root I created 2 files. Both files have 664 permission;
owner = ec2-user and group = www

```
index.php

<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matteolatitude
 * Date: 26/03/15
 * Time: 1.12
 */

include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/global.php');
include(PHP_FILES_PATH.'config.php');
echo '</br>';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
echo('Calculated result: '.$somma.'</br>');

global.php

<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matteolatitude
 * Date: 26/03/15
 * Time: 12.36
 */
define('PHP_FILES_PATH', '/var/mytest/');
```

Then I created /var/mytest dir with owner=root and group=root with 755 permission.
Then in /var/mytest I saved config.php; this file is only a test; in real app I will use it to store for example db connection data.
owner = root and group = root

```
config.php

<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matteolatitude
 * Date: 26/03/15
 * Time: 1.15
 */

// vediamo se esegue anche questo script
for ($k = 1; $k <= 4; $k++) {
    $somma .= $k*2;
}
```

I would like to know

1) Is include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/global.php') seems to be a good and secure choice? Is there a bettere and more secure method?

2) Are my permissions (and also owner and groups) a good choice or you would have done in a different way?

As you can see I'm very interested in security...

Thanks a lot,
Matt